# ruby gems that are included in gemfile and those that are not

Tags: rubygems, gemfile

When building with Ruby on Rails, I go to http://rubygems.org/ to download the gems. I have two options, I can install at the command line and I can add to my gemfile.

I seriously messed up my last project and I am wondering if it wasn't related to my understanding of gem installation and maintenance. I am using RVM and creating gemsets, so I am using the right tools (maybe not always the right way). My past behaviour was to 'gem install' in the command line and add same gem to the gemfile.

Question: What is the proper/best way to install a gem, and how would I know to install using both methods or just one? Is is normal to have a huge gemfile with 20-30 gems, most tutorials keep this very simple but my site keeps getting more complex?